# kvm does not log output

Tags: qemu, kvm

KVM tells me on `-help`:

```
-d item1,...    enable logging of specified items (use '-d help' for a list of log items)

-D logfile      output log to logfile (default stderr)
```

I used it:
`kvm -d in_asm,int -D mylog.log -boot d -cdrom myiso.iso -m 4069 -smp 4 -serial file:serial.log`

Using `qemu-system-x86_64` instead of `kvm`, everything is right, all output will be logged. But on enabling `kvm` (using `-enable-kvm` flag or command `kvm`), the file will be truncated but nothing logged.